# Product of independent beta distribution and gamma distribution

Tags: bayesian, joint-distribution, dynamic-regression

I'm reading *Bayesian Forecasting and Dynamic Models* by Mike West and Jeff Harrison. The following conclusion is about the variance discounting in dynamic linear regression model. On page 362, it says,

1. Dynamic of precision, $\phi_t=\gamma_t\phi_{t-1}/\delta$
2. Filtered precision distribution, $\phi_{t-1} \sim Gamma(n_{t-1}/2,d_{t-1}/2) $
3. Discounting factor, $\gamma_t \sim Beta(\delta n_{t-1}/2,(1-\delta) n_{t-1}/2) $

$\delta \in (0,1]$. Predicted precision distribution is,

$$\phi_t  \sim Gamma(\delta n_{t-1}/2,\delta d_{t-1}/2) $$

How to derive the predicted precision distribution?

I tried to apply transformation $U=\phi_t=\gamma_t\phi_{t-1}/\delta$ and auxiliary variable $V=\gamma_t$.

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{\gamma_t,\phi_{t-1}}(\gamma_t,\phi_{t-
1})|J(u,v)|$$

$J(u,v)$ is the Jacobian w.r.t to $U$ and $V$. But I can't integrate out $V$

Comment: Hi: I think Did'a answer here is the answer to your question but I'm too tired to even attempt to follow it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/how-exactly-are-the-beta-and-gamma-distributions-related

Comment: The correct transformation should be $U = \gamma_t \phi_{t-1}, V = (1-\gamma_t) \phi_{t-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand upon *why* the correct transformation is $U=\gamma_t\phi_{t-1}$ and $V=(1-\gamma_t)\phi_{t-1}$, consider the relation between the Gamma and Beta distributions. Specifically, consider independent random variables $X\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\theta)$ and $Y\sim\text{Gamma}(\beta,\theta)$. Then it follows $X(X+Y)^{-1}\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$. To see this, define the following transformations: $U=X(X+Y)^{-1}$ and auxiliary variable $V=X+Y$. The Jacobian of the inverse transformations $X=UV$ and $Y=V(1-U)$ is then equal to $V$, so it follows the joint distribution of $U$ and $V$ is equal to
\begin{aligned}
f_{U,V}(u,v)&=f_X(uv)f_Y(v(1-v))v\\
&={\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}(uv)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\theta uv}} \ {\frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)}(v(1-u))^{\beta-1}e^{-\theta v(1-u)}}v\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}v^{\alpha+\beta-1}e^{-\theta v}\times \frac{{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}u^{\alpha-1}(1-u)^{\beta-1},
\end{aligned}
implying $U$ and $V$ are independent. It follows the marginal of $U$ is distributed $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, while $V$ is distributed $\text{Gamma}(\alpha+\beta,\theta)$.

This suggests we instead start with independent random variables $U$ and $V$ as defined above and transform them through $X$ and $Y$ to achieve the desired Gamma marginal distribution for $X$. Taking $\alpha=\delta n_{t-1}$, $\beta=(1-\delta)n_{t-1}$ and $\theta=d_{t-1}$ achieves the desired result.